# Override default state based on service property?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My app has, of course, a default state that it displays when you hit it. I would like to potentially bypass that default state and nav to another state (representing a feature) based on the presence of a property (which I'm thinking will be read from a service). I'm not real sure how to approach this. It there some point of execution, or some event, that I can hook into to redirect the user from the default?

Comment: The property, btw, will/can be static or hard-coded, as I don't need it to change during the user's session.

Answer (score 1):

In a run block you can register a listener for $routeChangeSuccess or $stateChangeSuccess depending on if you're using ngRoute or ui-router.  The general syntax would look like:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).run(function($rootScope, $state, myService){
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if(myService.someValue && toState == 'defaultStateName')
      $state.go('otherState');
  })
});
```

Comment: I'll get to try this later, but I'm wondering if this will flash the default state before the '$state.go'.

Comment: Yeah probably, to stop it from getting to the state you can handle it in a resolve but that would need to be setup for any state other than the one you want it to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

I now have something that seems to do want I need fairly simply. Since I have my property on a service, I can inject that service into the controller for default content state. Right there in the controller I can check the property and call '$state.go' if I have to.